# How to group data by month in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a Google Sheet which contains various metrics for each day. Each day has it's own row:

```
day        | cost | impressions | clicks | conversions
2014-02-01 | $45  | 3,540       | 80     | 5
2014-02-02 | $49  | 3,700       | 88     | 7
2014-02-03 | $42  | 3,440       | 79     | 7
2014-02-04 | $51  | 3,940       | 91     | 10
```

I want to pivot the table and summarize the `cost`, `impressions`, `clicks` and `conversion` columns **by month** (not by day) like this:

```
Month        | Sum of cost | Sum of impressions | Sum of clicks | Sum of conversions
February     | $187        | 14620              | 338           | 29
```

In Excel I just used the `Group by` function, but I see it's not available in Google Sheets.

Comment: Correct answer as of 2018 is this one: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120852/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using the `Data->Pivot table report...` offers exactly what you are asking for.
It might be possible that you have to use the "*New Google Sheets*".

I use that as a default setting and it was easy to achieve what you wanted, similar as in Excel.

[Here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27967/alternating-colors-for-lines-in-google-docs-spreadsheet/54089#54089) in my answer I explain how to enable the new spreadsheets.

---

It seems I did not completly understand the problem.

First we need to have the month. For that add a new column to extract the date using `=MONTH(DATE_COLUMN)`.


[image]

Then create a Pivot report:

[image]

Comment: tried the 'new google sheets' and there's no option to group dates by month in the pivot table reports, maybe you could shed some light?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the main problem was that you couldn't find grouping at all. Then why not adding a column that provides the month only and group by it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add in another column, or change the formatting of the source sheet as it's being used to power a dashboard in Cyfe, but thanks for your answers...

Comment: You can add the column, then hide it so it is invisible. Still you can use it in the Pivot report.

Comment: Excellent idea. I tried it, however Cyfe doesn't seem to be able to  ignore the hidden columns. I'm just going to have to maintain 2 duplicate sheets with the source data to work around this....

Comment: You might want to look at IMPORTRANGE() function to read the data from a different sheet. Although I think this function is not (yet) supported in the new sheets.

Answer (score 67):

### Google Sheets now supports this as 'Create pivot date group'

*In the Pivot table*, once you've added your date/time column as rows:

1. Right-click on one of the values in the Pivot table,
2. Choose 'Create pivot date group'
3. Choose the desired grouping (e.g., 'Month' or 'Year-Month')

#### Before + Visual Example:

[image: Pivot table before grouping]

#### After:

[image]

#### More Info

- Google's documentation on the feature: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7572895

Comment: this should be the right answer probably

Comment: This is the best answer by far as of 2018

Comment: Can I use my own formulae with Pivot tables somehow? I want to get quantiles

Comment: I don't see this option in my date column

Comment: @IanHyzy Make sure the column in your source data set is formatted as date.

Comment: @IanHyzy I was also confused by this — couldn't find the option. Then realized it's _after_ you create the pivot table and you right-click on any of the dates in the pivot table (not on the sheet that has your original data), hope that helps!

Answer (score 7):

Without a helper column:

```
=query(A:E,"select sum(B), sum(C), sum(D), sum (E) group by month(A) offset 1")
```

assuming `day` is in A1.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) that does a much better job of describing how the above works than ever I could.

Comment: This sounds really useful. Could you explain how it works? I've never used the Query function.

Comment: Is it possible to group by month AND year?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Yes, it is

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Try `=query(A:C,"select avg(B), avg(C) group by DAY(A), MONTH(A), YEAR(A)")`

Answer (score 6):

So for those who asked similar question as me, 
There is apparently no Group field function for Pivot in Google Sheet (as it there is in Excel) yet. 
Hence the simplest way is to add another column transforming your dates to the groups you need, e.g. weeks, months, years...
Hopefully the functionality is soon in Google sheet too.

Answer (score 5):

An easier way that I found was to convert the date cell to text in a new column.

```
=Text(A1, "mmm-yy")
```

You can then pivot and it will group by month.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way I like better.  I simply created a hidden column with the following steps:

---

- Round every day of the month to the first day of the month.

> =A2 - day(A2) + 1 where A2 is the standard date

- Set the formatting to custom and choose month / year.  This will require you to delete the day setting.  So, it will display month / year when the actual value will be first day of month, month, year.
- The pivot table will now group all similar items together and display formatting from the column with month / year.

This way you'll get unique values as the years pass by.  Myself I decided to hide the column in question because I have a Doc connected to this Sheet that pulls the first two rows as I add them.

[image: Formula for date and formatting]

[image: Custom Date Format]

[image: Pivot Table Results]

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers worked for me, because I use a form as input. You can't add formulas on the form-sheet.

Here is my work-around.

Reading the above, the Pivot table needs a column with month to select on. You can use a different criteria, like week or fridays. Or John, Doe, Foo or bar. Whatever you want to 'group'on.

In my case: date is in B, `=month(B2)` gives the month. So I needed an extra column with `=month(B2)`.

Form-sheet doesn't allow formulas. And on a sheet with a form, you can't add a column with formulas (exactly: you can, but a new form-entry deletes the formula on the corresponding line).

## Second sheets

A simple second sheet with `=page1!A1` etc and adding the column month has the same problem. A new entry in the form => adds a row.

## Solution

So I did the following.

- Added an extra sheet
- Used `=importrange("longkeynumber";"sheet form!A1:E1000")` on A1
- (importrange is to import a different document, but hey … it works)
- In F, used `=if(B3>0;(MONTH(B3));"")`
- When adding extra data in sheet A, formulas in sheet B with the importrange stays.
- Now you can add a pivot table, with (in this case) F as a row or column.

Comment: In user165410's [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/75391), he states: - In F, used `=if(B3>0;(MONTH(B3));"")` This is a good solution, but it can be made even easier: - in F3, `=arrayformula(if(b3:b>0;(month(b3:b));""))` What this does, is automatically put the month for every non-empty cell in the range B3:B. Inserting or deleting a row, or moving a row will NOT screw up the formulas!

Comment: When a new responses is added to a spreadsheet, a new row is inserted. Array formulas (multiple values result) could be used instead or scalar formulas (single values results). By the other hand, when the source data comes from the same file you could use array formulas to return the same result as IMPORTRANGE and they updated immediately

Comment: I love this solution! in F3, =arrayformula(if(b3:b>0;(month(b3:b));"")) Only problem is when the data is for more than one year and each month gets combined with the same month in the previous year.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already adding a new column, you can also just use `eomonth("reference cell",0)`.  That'll always grab the last day of the month.  Or `eomonth("reference cell",-1)+1` to get the beginning of the month.

The beauty with this approach instead of converting to text is that when you pivot the data.  It'll automatically sort ascending left to right.