# Sum category column in one sheet based on a dates column in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

I have a sheet, `Transactions`, that looks like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|         Date |       Payee |    Category |    Amount |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   29/03/2020 |     Walmart |   Groceries |   $100.00 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|   27/02/2020 |      Costco |   Groceries |   $220.00 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|   12/03/2020 |       Exxon |         Gas |   $350.00 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|   05/01/2020 |    Petsmart |        Pets |    $50.00 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|   28/03/2020 |       Shell |         Gas |   $125.00 |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Now, in another sheet, I want to keep track of how much I'm spending in each category every month. I want it to look like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    Category |   03/2020 |   02/2020 |   01/2020 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         Gas |           |           |           |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|   Groceries |           |           |           |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|        Pets |           |           |           |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

So in the end, each column should look like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    Category |   03/2020 |   02/2020 |   01/2020 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         Gas |   $475.00 |        $0 |        $0 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|   Groceries |   $100.00 |   $220.00 |        $0 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|        Pets |        $0 |        $0 |    $50.00 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have the following query in the cell B2, but it's not working:

```
=iferror(query(INDIRECT("Transactions!A2:D"), "Select A, B, C, D", "select Sum(D) where A >= date '"&TEXT(B$1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&TEXT(eomonth(B$1,0),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and C= '"&$A2&"' label Sum(D) ''"),0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregating data by date between tabs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/140914/aggregating-data-by-date-between-tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is basically correct. It will work with minor alterations.

Please use the following and drag down and then to the right:

```
=iferror(query(Transactions!$A$2:$D, "select Sum(D) where A >= date '"&TEXT(B$1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&TEXT(eomonth(B$1,0),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and C= '"&$A2&"' label Sum(D) ''"),0)
```

What changed:

1. You do not need the `INDIRECT` function in your query. You just need to lock the query range using the `$` sign: `Transactions!$A$2:$D`
2. You used the `select` clause twice. It should be used just once.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.