# Google spreadsheets group by date (year-month) AND another column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to group the data into a table so that I can group the DATE column into a month + year and at the same time differentiate the segment.

[image]

In MySQL something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(Date), '-',MONTH(Date)) AS MonthYear, Segment, SUM(Price) FROM table GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(Date), '-',MONTH(Date)), Segment
```

From this I then need to create a stacked graph. I was looking for various tutorials but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. There are a lot of ways to do this, i.e. using pivot tables, formulas using functions like QUERY, using Google Apps Script... Have you already searched this site? Have you  used pivot tables before?

Comment: Hello, i want solving it with pivot table. Yes i before tried pivod tables, but no with "multiple grouping". I i tried this, pivot makes me for each "Segment" another column and then I can't create a graph from that

Comment: but in the end I can have any other solution

Comment: Related: [How to group data by month in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58055/88163) (Duplicate?)

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula, then select the output and insert a chart (Stacked Column)

`=query({B2:B7,ArrayFormula(EOMONTH(A2:A7,0)),C2:C7},"Select Col2, Sum(Col3) group by Col2 pivot Col1  format Col2'MMM-YYYY'")`

**Logic:**

- **Query data**

  - three separate ranges contained within curly brackets and separated by commas (array values)
  - the month/year value is derived by using `EOMONTH()`, and the date format is generated in the query by `format Col2'MMM-YYYY'`
  - the data is grouped by date
- **Pivot Table**

  - the selected data are: Month/Year and summed Segment value
  - the pivot value is the Segment.

---

**Data, Pivot Table and Stacked Column graph**

[image: Data, Pivot Table and Stacked Column graph]

---

**Credit:**

Applied the logic described in infoinspired.com: [How to Group Data by Month and Year in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/group-data-by-month-and-year-in-google-sheets/)